# Getting Host header from web application

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, url, web-application, host-header

i want to get host header from web application programatically:
for example in below code i got absolute url of web application "http://example.com" in RootUrl variable, from this web application, i want to get host header `"example.com"`, how it can be done?

```
RootUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.GetAbsoluteUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should provide the details you need, depending on if you want the root site, or site collection URL, or host name.

```
// Root Site – eg. Web App URL
var rootSiteCollectionURL = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].Url;

// Site Collection URL
var SiteCollectionURL = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url;

// Host Name of current Site Collection (Machine Name)
var HostName - SPContext.Current.Site.HostName
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.hostname(v=office.12).aspx

You can use SPContext.Current.Site.HostName to get the host name.